# SQL command to remove groups of entries where all are equal (not merely DISTINCT)

Tags: sql, filter

i am so green in SQL that I don't even know how to properly phrase my question or look for an existing answer in stack overflow or anywhere else. Sorry!

Assume i have 3 columns. One is an ID and two data columns A and B. A single ID can have multiple entries. I like to remove all entries, where A and B are same for a given ID. Probably i give an example

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | x | y |
| 01 | x | y |
| 01 | x | y |
| 02 | x | y |
| 02 | x | z |
| 02 | x | y |

In this table I would like to remove all 3 entries that belong to ID 01 as A as well as B are all x and y, respectively. For ID 02, however, column B differs for the first and second entry. Therefore I like to keep ID 02. I hope this illustrates the idea sufficiently :-).

I am look for a 'scalable' solution, as I am not only looking at two data columns A and B, but actually 4 different columns.

Does anyone know how to set a proper filter in SQL to remove those entries according to my needs?

Many thanks.

Benjamin

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `DELETE` the records by using an inner join on the same table `where t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B AND t1.ID = t2.ID` Something along those lines. That would delete all the rows where `ID, A, B` are not distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for this, it basically doesn't matter how many coumns you actually have, as long as they are identical

this can be used for an as joining basis for a `DELETE`

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (SELECT DISTINCT "ID", "A", "B" FROM tab1),
> CTE2 AS (SELECT "ID", COUNT(*) count_ FROM CTE GROUP BY "ID" HAVING COUNT(*)  >1) 
> SELECT "ID" FROM CTE2
> ```
>
> ```
> | ID |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3ed12330b379a1e6dea747e019609f1a)*

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for these lines. I was able to get what I want modifying your code. Great.